# How to aggregate data with ETL (AWS Glue) so we can use Athena to select by certain attribute for only a percentage of data

Tags: pyspark, bigdata, etl, aws-glue, amazon-athena

If there's a better place to ask this type of question, please let me know.

I have a service that stores and attempts to read documents. For each document, the service will extract and read the lines and words with a certain confidence.

The payload for a single document (pre ETL) looks like the following

```
{
        "Blocks": [
            {
                "Type": "LINE",
                "Confidence": 90
                "Value": "this is a sentence"
                ...
            },
            {
                "Type": "WORD",
                "Confidence": 99
                "Value": "this"
                ...
            },
            {
                "Type": "WORD",
                "Confidence": 97
                "Value": "is"
                ...
            },
            {
                "Type": "WORD",
                "Confidence": 89
                "Value": "a"
                ...
            },
            {
                "Type": "WORD",
                "Confidence": 99
                "Value": "sentence"
                ...
            },
            {
                "Type": "WORD",
                "Confidence": 50
            },
            {
                "Type": "LINE",
                "Confidence": 90
                "Value": "example of another line"
                ...
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
```

I'm looking for a high level algorithm or ideas for an ETL aggregate function so I can use Athena to make a query that will give me something like

"give me all document where 30% of the words have confidence > 60"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an etl, athena can read json natively, see

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-JSON.html

Aftet you created your table, it's a matter of writing the right query for your task. Your statement "give me all docs with x% of words having some confidende" is pretty standard. The details depend on how you define your table colns, but you could do sth like:

```
SELECT docid from mytable group by docid
 having count_if(confidende>60)* 1./count(*) > 0.3
```

Comment: hi, thanks for asnwering, yes we considered this approach as well, but our json can go up to several mb. Also the querying can be quite complex. So we want a solution where we can bring our aggregated data to top level for simpler queries. I think I found a workable solution though, I can probably just aggregate the data as a map representation of a histogram of % distribution.